# CPU temp monitoring tools freezes the laptop

Tags: cpu, fan, temperature

I have a problem running any form of CPU temp monitoring app on my Ubuntu(and same on Mint) on my old Dell Studio 1737(A09).

Whether I install `psensor`, `sensors`, `lm-senors` or `i8kutils` (this last one crashes the PC) the laptop freezes and I can't do anything until I restart and remove the package.

I had dual boot before (Windows 7) and did not have any problem monitoring CPU temperature so I am guessing it is related to my OS, not the hardware.

I ended up installing fan control which detects the fan and functions ok but I have to set intervals to 3600s to not to check on CPU often since every time it tries to check the CPU temp, my screen freezes for a few seconds and then is released until the next check. Any attempt by me to check the CPU temp (running 'sensors' in terminal) freezes everything.